# How to create random sample points in arcgis?

Tags: arcgis

I need to select random sample locations in my study area to test for null model(statistical significance). That sample should make random sample (of area >0.05ha) from original sample.
How to select random sample with a define area e.g., I use create random points then used extra multi value to point but cant define area to select from my data tobe > 0.05 hacter.

Comment: Which programming language do you use to access arcgis? What have you tried so far? Please read [ask].